# Gitkraken, Git LFS not found on OSX

Tags: git-lfs, gitkraken

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwDj5.png)

Hi,
I'm trying to have Gitkraken detect my Git LFS install but impossible on osx whereas it is in the usual path :
which git-lfs
/usr/local/bin/git-lfs

Any idea?